# overflow hidden on ul causing a jump

Tags: html, css

so when adding an overflow hidden on this ul (which i want for hiding other items in the list) is causing the whole ul to jump about 10px up, can anyone suggest why this might be happening?
i have left the inline css on so it's easy to toggle to see

```
     <ul style="
    /* max-height: 25px; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /* margin: 0; */">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mt7qpn3L/
[image]

P.S. i know there are other ways to accomplish my hidden list but i'm curious why this is happening and a solution

Comment: Does the first child of the `ul` have a top `margin`?

Comment: I think it's because of the height of each text is different.

Comment: What exactly do you want to have happen? You have your list elements as inline-block so they will continue to wrap on the same line. `vertical-align: middle` on both `ul` and `li` will center everything.

Comment: If you want to align them in same height then use vertical-align:middle; in ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align: middle` on both `ul` and `li` css selectors will center everything.

Answer (score 2):

set ul `display: inline;` in your style

and remove comment on `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 2):

Govind is on the right track. I just thought I'd answer *why*. It has to do with the text baseline, which is the default setting for vertical-align (`vertical-align: baseline`).

An interesting side point is that if you remove the UTF-8 characters (中国) the baseline will jump a few pixels since the baseline is different for those characters. CSS baseline is actually dependent on `line-height`. It is misleading since you expect the baseline to be the line where letters "sit", but the actual baseline overflows the bottom of the ul.

Thus when you add `overflow: hidden;` The `<ul>` will shrink to smallest possible height where everything is still visible. And your baseline, which no longer overflows, is now effectively cut to be at the bottom of the element. Therefore everything will jump around when you change overflow.

I think this is a good read about css-baselines: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/

Comment: yes, although Govind and Bhargav both had solutions correct to this situation, this comment is really interesting about the different character sets baselines, this probably is an issue that doesn't come up too often